# In angular4 where is the implementation of component in @angular/core?

Tags: angular

In the file app.component.ts Line 1
import { Component } from 'angular/core';
I have not been able to locate the implementation of Component in the folder.

Comment: Here: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/metadata/directives.ts#L479

Comment: Thanks @HarryNinh

Comment: @HarryNinh that is not an implementation, it's an interface. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44877931/2545680).

Comment: @DavidSagang that is not an implementation, it's an interface. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44877931/2545680).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of the decorator `Component` is comprised of two parts:

[makeDecorator function](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7edc5e96f373d7c74092b92874fa6c69b308d8dc/packages/core/src/util/decorators.ts#L264) - this where the main functionality is implemented, particularly defining metadata on the class:

```
const TypeDecorator: TypeDecorator = <TypeDecorator>function TypeDecorator(cls: Type<any>) {
    const annotations = Reflect.getOwnMetadata('annotations', cls) || [];
    annotations.push(annotationInstance);
    Reflect.defineMetadata('annotations', annotations, cls);
    return cls;
};
```

and [component decorator properties](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7edc5e96f373d7c74092b92874fa6c69b308d8dc/packages/core/src/metadata/directives.ts#L693) which defines the default properties of the `Component` decorator:

```
export const Component: ComponentDecorator = <ComponentDecorator>makeDecorator(
    'Component', {
        selector: undefined,
        inputs: undefined,
        outputs: undefined,
        host: undefined,
        exportAs: undefined,
        moduleId: undefined,
        providers: undefined,
        viewProviders: undefined,
        changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default,
        ...
```

You might want to read the article [Implementing custom component decorator in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/implementing-custom-component-decorator-in-angular-4d037d5a3f0d)

Comment: must be a comment

Comment: what makes you think so? I'm going to edit and add more information now

Comment: okay, can you maybe point to the guide where it says the answer should be a comment if there's no code in it?